# how do i get back information from a form using php

Tags: php, html

html code:

```
<form  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_file.php"
method="POST">
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Browse for file to upload: <br>
<input name="file" type="file" id="file" size="80"> <br>
<input type="submit" id="u_button" name="u_botton" value="Upload the File">
</p>
</form>
```

php code:

```
<?php
$file_result = "";

 if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
 {
 $_file_result .= "No File Upload or Invalid File";
 $_file_result .= "Error Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
 } else {

 $file_result .=
 "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>" .
 "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>" .
 "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . "Kb<br>" .
 "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>" .

 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
 "" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

 $file_result .= "File Upload Successful !";
 }
print " Now just go to www.example.com/ the name of the thing you uploaded "
?>
```

I am trying to get information from an html form, I am allowing people to upload to my server and I am trying to get the name of the file they uploaded
 How do I do that?

Comment: you are saving your file in some folder or somewhere else?

Comment: @anantkumarsingh what do you mean?

Comment: Means when you are saving your file try to save its path in some database table based on user id or name and then retrieve them to show. Or please specify what do you mean by "get back information?"

Comment: @anantkumarsingh imean like when you upload your file it has a name i want php to automatically to fill the name of the file uploaded in the section "the name of the thing you uploaded"

Comment: then just  write it. print " Now just go to www.example.com/ ".$_FILES["file"]["name"]." ";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `var_dump` it. It will show all the information you need.

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($_FILES["file"]);
echo "</pre>";
?>

$fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];

echo "File name is : " . $fileName;
```

It will print,

```
array(5) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(10) "assume.png"
  ["type"]=>
  string(9) "image/png"
  ["tmp_name"]=>
  string(14) "/tmp/phpe9vaQc"
  ["error"]=>
  int(0)
  ["size"]=>
  int(12969)
}

File name is : assume.png
```

Here, `assume.png` was the original file name which i chose from my computer.

**EDIT** : Since your question is solely based on how to get the filename which was submitted from the form, the answer is above.

If you want to store the image to database, then

1. Move the file to some folder like `upload` or `images` & get the upload path.
2. Store the path to database like `upload/someone.jpg`.

Good luck!

Comment: I see but what if I just want the name

Comment: Okay nvm Anat kumar singh answered my question